# Kotlin: How to get a type of a method parameter

Tags: kotlin

I know I can get the type of a method parameter by using "Method#parameters#name".

**However,** my parameters are all the subclass of `A` and I **dont** want to get the type `A`. I want to get the subclass name.

```kotlin
if (checkMethod(i)) {
    val type = i.parameters[0].simpleName
    if (!functions.containsKey(type)) {
        functions[type] = HashMap()
    }
    if (!functions[type]?.containsKey(identifier)!!) {
        functions[type]?.put(identifier, ArrayList())
    }
    functions[type]?.get(identifier)?.add(i)
}
```

#### Final Solution:

```kotlin
    private fun analysis(clazz: KClass<EventHandler>, identifier: String) {
        clazz.members.forEach {
            if(it is KFunction) {
                if(checkMethod(it)) {
                    val type = methodEventType(it)
                    if(!invokeMethods.containsKey(type)) invokeMethods[type] = HashMap()
                    if(!invokeMethods[type]!!.containsKey(identifier)) invokeMethods[type]!![identifier] = ArrayList()
                    invokeMethods[type]!![identifier]!!.add(it.javaMethod)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun checkMethod(method: KFunction<*>): Boolean {
        method.annotations.forEach {
            if(it is EventSubscriber) {
                val type = method.parameters[1].type.classifier
                if(type is KClass<*>) {
                    if(method.parameters.size == 2 && type.superclasses.contains(Event::class)) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

And notice here. I dont know why the method`s first parameter is allways a instance of its class. So the real parameter is start from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Your `if statements` scream this is `javascript`.  Please edit your tags accordingly.

Comment: This is not valid Java code (no semicolons, using `val` as a type, `obj?.method()` syntax). Have you executed any code yourself? What are you able to get with which code and where do you get stuck? There is not enough information here to answer your question.

Comment: Its kotlin... i thought its same with java. i will change it

Comment: You're using a lot of reflection. Reflection is an advanced topic that it's early to be diving into if you're just now learning that Kotlin isn't Java, and you probably don't need for what you're doing. I sometimes see Javascript programmers trying to use it when they are just beginning with a strongly-typed language, but reflection should generally be avoided. You mostly see it in libraries for generating code or parsing JSON/XML/etc into classes.

Comment: infact i change to kotlin from java only about 1month. lots new stuff still dont known. thanks. and im making a event system with reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you'll find this example useful (works with `kotlin-reflect:1.4.21`)

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.full.createType
import kotlin.reflect.full.isSubtypeOf
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.reflect

open class A
val aType = A::class.createType()

class B: A()
class C: A()

val foo = { b: B, c: C ->
    println(b)
    println(c)
}

println(foo.reflect()!!.parameters[0].type.classifier == B::class) // true
println(foo.reflect()!!.parameters[1].type.classifier == C::class) // true
println(foo.reflect()!!.parameters[0].type.isSubtypeOf(aType)) // true
```

To get all subclasses

```kotlin
println((foo.reflect()!!.parameters[0].type.classifier as KClass<*>).allSuperclasses.contains(A::class)) // true
```

Comment: So i have tested. Maybe my question describe not so clear. I mean getting the subclass of A. Not A.Thanks

Comment: If you are sure your parameter is a class, you can do the following cast. Then you will get access to collection of its superClasses.
I added example to answer.

Comment: Im not checking the type of the parameter. im getting the type. if i use i.parameters[0].simpleName it will return A but not B (B extends A). and now i want get B not A. Thanks!

Comment: See, when you get collection of superclasses of parameter by `.allSuperclasses`, you don't have to check if you don't need it. Collection basically contains all the super classes up to `Any`.
To get the closest superclass, just get first element of this collection

Comment: And to get `B` simply `foo.reflect()!!.parameters[0].type.classifier`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the class of the first parameter:

```kotlin
i.parameters[0]::class.java
```

Comment: So. this actully will return a Parameter not A or the subclass of A